# Send Multi-Threading SMTP emails

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, smtp

I have developed an application which primarily sends email messages uses SMTP.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("from", "to");
mail.Subject = "subject";
mail.Body = "body";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("my domain");
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, "MyPass");
client.Send(mail);
```

This works fine but now i want to send several messages in the same time without to wait so i put all my messages in a list:

```
List<MailMessage> emails = new List<MailMessage>();
emails.Add(new MailMessage (...));
emails.Add(new MailMessage (...));
emails.Add(new MailMessage (...));
...
```

And i want to open new `Thread` of each email:

```
// Generate and execute all mails concurrently
var emailTasks = emails.Select(msg =>
                 {
                     client = new SmtpClient();
                     return client.SendAsync(msg);
                 });

// Asynchronously wait for all of them to complete.
await Task.WhenAll(emailTasks);
```

And got this error:

> There is no SendMailAsync, and the last code line is also with error:
>   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're making multiple SMTP calls on the same `SmtpClient` instance which is captured by all your threads.

You can see it inside the source code of [`SmtpClient.Send`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,cca069628a6b9b57) (Shortened for brevity):

```
try 
{
    // If there is already an ongoing SMTP request
    if (InCall)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.net_inasync));
    }
}
```

Generally, you don't need to use any threads to do I/O bound operations, as they are asynchronous by nature.

Instead, you can use `async-await` to take advantage of the asynchronous API:

```
// Generate and execute all mails concurrently
var emailTasks = emails.Select(msg => 
                 {
                    var client = new SmtpClient();
                    return client.SendMailAsync(msg));
                 });

// Asynchronously wait for all of them to complete.
await Task.WhenAll(emailTasks);
```

Comment: Where i need to put this code ? and SendAsync expected more argument (object userToken) - what should i put here ?

Comment: `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`, Not `SendAsync`.

Comment: There is no SendMailAsync, and the last code line is also  with error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Comment: @Maggy Please edit your question with the complete method execution so i can answer properly